# Error en Laravel 8 al hacer una consulta

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, laravel-8

Hola estoy creando un ecomerce en laravel 8 pero me da un error en la siguiente consulta con su relación incluida, el caso es que lo tengo todo bien relacionado pero no logro rellenar la tabla Color_Product con registros aplicando el filtro.

Pego las tablas y el código.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateSubcategoriesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('subcategory', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('image');
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->boolean('color')->default(false);
            $table->boolean('size')->default(false);
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('subcategories');
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Añade el código de tus modelos

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que veo rápidamente, es que las FK están en plural, cuando deberían estar en singular. Laravel busca subcategory_id y en la tabla tenes subcategories_id. Recorda que tenes que usar las FK en singular.

Answer (score 0):

Hola en tu funcion subCategory deberas añadir el nombre de la llave foranea y la llave local para que concuerde

```
return $this->hasMany(SubCategory::class, 'id', 'subcategories' );
```